# Ajax jQuery not always executes action on Controller

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have the Controller method below made in ASP.NET MVC 3 (C#) who returns a PartialView:

```
public ActionResult InsertEmail(long idPerson)
    {
        PersonEmailViewModel mail = new PersonEmailViewModel();
        mail.email.Person_idPerson = idPerson;
        return PartialView(mail);
    }
```

The method that I need to execute on submit form is:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertNewEmail(PersonEmail mail)
    {
        mail.idPersonEmail = mail.Insert(mail);
        return Json(mail);
    }
```

My partialView contains this code:

```
@model PlatformLib_MySql.BLL.Person.PersonEmailViewModel
<form action="" id="frmNewEmail" method="post">
<div>
E-mail: @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.email.email))
@(Html.HiddenFor(m => m.email.Person_idPerson))
<input type="submit" value="Insert" id="btnSubmitMailInsert" />
<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnCancelMailInsert" />
</div>
</form>
```

In my JS file I run this code on #btnSubmitMailInsert button:

```
jQuery("#btnSubmitMailInsert").click(function () {
submitNewEmail();
window.location.reload();
});
function submitNewEmail() {
event.preventDefault();
var mail = {
    email: jQuery("#frmNewEmail #email_email").val(),
    Person_idPerson: jQuery("#frmNewEmail #email_Person_idPerson").val()
};

var request = jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/Person/InsertNewEmail',
    data: mail,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false
});

request.done(function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});

request.fail(function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
}
```

My problem is focused on Ajax request. Rarely I can make the "happy way", where on submit click, the event is activated on jQuery, calls the method "submitNewEmail()", that calls an Ajax, executes the method on controller and pass with success. But not so... It always returns with fail, not because error returned by controller method, but simply because ajax doesn't runs properly, doesn't execute the method on controller, even with a breakpoint inserted there (on VS2010).
In this JS code posted by me here is an attempt to alternatively solve this problem, unsuccessful.
The original code is:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/Person/InsertNewEmail',
    data: mail,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        debugger;
        jQuery("#tblEmail").append("<tr><td>Email inserido</td></tr>");
    },
    error: function () {
        debugger;
        alert("Erro ao inserir e-mail.");
    }
});
```

I left the "console.log(msg)" temporary, just to solve this problem.

Can someone of you tell me what is happening, or to point where is my error?

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` move this inside `jQuery("#btnSubmitMailInsert").click(function () {`

Comment: Can you try setting the content type of the ajax request to"application/json" and JSON.Stringify() in the data to convert it to json string..

Comment: @Murali It is a mere detail.

Comment: @Saranya Yes, but the result was the same :-(

Comment: Can you provide class definition of PersonEmail class.. just to check

Comment: @Saranya
This class is a DAO, which is too long to post.
Attributes:
public long idPersonEmail { get; set; }
public long Person_idPerson { get; set; }
public string email { get; set; }
Methods:
public long Insert(PersonEmail email)
public bool Delete(PersonEmail email)

Comment: you have three properties in your class but you are sending only 2 from ajax.. guess that is a prob. can you try hardcoding some values to data like JSON.Stringify({"idPersonEmail":"123, "Person_idPerson":"xyz","email":98})

Comment: @Saranya In the view is used only two of these properties. The property 'idPersonEmail' is set inside the method with HttpPost. Reinforcing what I said, sometimes the ajax executes the controller method, but not always. Look that we don't have in the view the property 'idPersonEmail' used. It is a primary key of a database table, auto-incremented.

Comment: @Matheus,I understand your code logic. but from what i know, the server will try to deserialize the JSON string you send into the type you specify in the method signature. when that fails, your method will not be called. can you just give a try passing the third parameter as well?

Comment: @Saranya I tried it now, but... no success. How as I said, the method is not being called. I put a breakpoint in the first line after declaration, but it isn't executed. I changed the ajax code now to: jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/Person/InsertNewEmail',
        data: mail,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
    }).done(function () {
        alert('OK');

    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }); It only works on browser debugger mode.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Everything was right, but some detail damaged the code: window.location.reload();

I made some changes in my code, that looks like it:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/Person/InsertNewEmail',
    data: mail,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false
}).done(function (data) {
    // Do something
});
```

The another way is right too, the only relevant change was:

```
jQuery("#btnSubmitMailInsert").click(function () {
event.preventDefault();
submitNewEmail();
// window.location.reload // -> Commented for testing and everything worked fine.
});
```

Thanks for trying to help me. This helped me so much.